# Which test is suitable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have data from which I have to infer which day of a week is significant in terms of emotions. Please suggest me which statistical test I should use.

```
            Fri  Mon  Sat  Sun  Thu  Tue  Wed
  negative 1047  999  486  400 1120 1466 1339
  neutral  1218 1112  570  474 1263 1642 1413
  positive 2446 2281 1026  755 2544 3785 3116
```

Data set showing the number of occurrences of negative, positive and neutral on specific days of the week.

Comment: This seems to be one of several recent questions on similar data simply asking what test to use, and without any substantive statement of purpose or context, and without suggestions of your own. You will get better responses from more informative questions.

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by "significant in terms of emotions"?  The mean is not at all clear and several reasonable interpretations are possible, depending on whether you are detecting lack of independence, large relative frequencies, large average frequencies, large ranges, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Putting your counts into matrix `MAT` for chi-squared homogeneity
of distribution test.

```
MAT = matrix(c(1047,  999,  486,  400, 1120, 1466, 1339,
               1218, 1112,  570,  474, 1263, 1642, 1413,
               2446, 2281, 1026,  755, 2544, 3785, 3116), nrow=3)
```

Highly, significant result: P-value almost 0.

```
chisq.test(MAT)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 2833.6, df = 12, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Look at Pearson residuals for clues to interpretation. The sum of
squared Pearson residuals is the chi-squared statistic, so from
them one can see where Observed counts deviate most greatly from
Expected counts based on the null hypothesis. In this case, perhaps
look at especially at residuals with absolute values above 10.

```
round(chisq.test(MAT)$res, 3)
#       Fri     Mon    Sat     Sun    Tue     Thu    Wed
        [,1]    [,2]   [,3]    [,4]   [,5]    [,6]   [,7]
[1,]   8.110 -18.111  4.580  -6.345 -3.078  26.898 -9.024  # Neg
[2,]   5.751   4.391  0.314 -10.345 -9.327  -8.490 12.156  # Neu
[3,] -13.375  13.135 -4.705  16.140 12.014 -17.596 -3.134  # Pos
```

I agree with @rw2 that the interesting parts are most easily
summarized in terms of emotion categories. Among 'Pos' subjects
there are than the expected number of counts on Sun-Tue and
fewer than expected on Thu & Fri. Among 'Neg' subjects there more
counts than expected on Thu and fewer on Mon.

This seems more meaningful than regression results that all days
are more or less weird (except possibly less so for Thu). In fact, *Thu makes a larger contribution than any other day* to the 
very large and highly significant chi-squared statistic.

Answer (score -1):

You are  dealing with count data, so a (Poisson) generalized linear model will do. Here are the results in R

```
dat=read.table(text="
           Fri  Mon  Sat  Sun  Thu  Tue  Wed
  negative 1047  999  486  400 1120 1466 1339
  neutral  1218 1112  570  474 1263 1642 1413
  positive 2446 2281 1026  755 2544 3785 3116")
dat2=unlist(dat)
dat3=data.frame(
  "cnt"=dat2,
  "grp"=factor(substr(names(dat2),1,3))
)
```

and the model

```
summary(glm(cnt~grp,data=dat3,family=poisson))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  7.35904    0.01457 505.102  < 2e-16 ***
grpMon      -0.07012    0.02098  -3.343 0.000829 ***
grpSat      -0.81657    0.02632 -31.028  < 2e-16 ***
grpSun      -1.06193    0.02874 -36.946  < 2e-16 ***
grpThu       0.04483    0.02038   2.200 0.027806 *  
grpTue       0.38061    0.01890  20.134  < 2e-16 ***
grpWed       0.21961    0.01956  11.226  < 2e-16 ***
```

Comment: But doesn't this just test for a different average count between days?  It doesn't seem to take into account the differences between negative, neutral and positive emotions. Maybe some kind of multinomial model would work?

Comment: @rw2 Yes, that is how I interpreted it, global difference between days.